# ¿Como puedo enviar parametros y a su vez recibirlos en un componente donde creo mi StackNavigator? React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

espero me puedan ayudar con lo siguiente:

Tengo mi archivo **App.js** donde obtengo un token al iniciar sesión, pues bien, una vez se se inicia sesión cargo otro componente llamado **Principal.js**, en este creo mi StackNavigator donde genero las rutas, pues bien necesito enviar el toke recibido en **App.js** a **Principal.js** para que asi en **Principal.js** enviarlo como parametro a las rutas (ya lo ultimo lo tengo resuelto)

**Aqui mi codigo en App.js**

```js
import React from "react";
import Principal from "./Principal";
import Login from "./Login";
import NavegacionPrincipal from "./NavegacionPrincipal";
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    token: "",
    usuario: ""
  };

  cargaToken = token => {
    this.setState({
      token: token
    });
  };

  enviaToken = () => {
    return this.state.token;
  };

  render() {
    if (this.state.token != "") {
      return <Principal screenProps={this.state.token} />;
    } else {
      return <Login cargaToken={this.cargaToken} />;
      //return <NavegacionPrincipal />;
    }
  }
}
```

**Aqui mi código en Principal.js**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"; //<====== solo para envio de parametros
import { Text, View } from "react-native"; //<====== solo para envio de parametros
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import Home from "./Home";
import Navegacion from "./Navegacion";
import Configuracion from "./Configuracion";
import ConductorInfo from "./ConductorInfo";
import SeleccionPPU from "./SeleccionPPU";
import Siniestros from "./Siniestros";

retornaToken = () => {
  const valorToken = Inicio;
  return valor;
};

class Inicio extends React.Component {
  obtieneToken() {
    const token = this.props.screenProps;
    console.log("el token es:" + token);
  }
}
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Home: { screen: <Home tokenLlave={this.props.screenProps} /> },
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
      params: { token: Inicio }
    },
    Navegacion: { screen: Navegacion },
    Configuracion: { screen: Configuracion },
    ConductorInfo: { screen: ConductorInfo },
    SeleccionPPU: { screen: SeleccionPPU },
    Siniestros: { screen: Siniestros }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Como ven, en:

```js
Home: {
          screen: Home,
          params: { token: Inicio }
        },
```

estoy enviando como parámetro (en **Principal.js**) el token en la ruta, pero no logro recibirlo de **App.js**

Gracias a quienes me pueden ayudar en lograr recibir el parámetro desde **App.js** en el componente donde armo las rutas (**Principal.js**) :)

Version de react-native-cli: 2.0.1 
Version de react-native: 0.57.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los parametros que pasas con `screenProps` ya está en las 'screens' y los puedes usar con `this.props.screenProps`cómo https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#navigator-props.

```js
<SomeStack
  screenProps={/* this prop will get passed to the screen components as this.props.screenProps */}
/>
```

Los **estas haciendo mal, eso si, en App.js  Correcto es: `screenProps={ { token: this.state.token } }`**

```js
...
render() {
    if (this.state.token != "") {
      return <Principal screenProps={ { token: this.state.token } } />;
    } else {
      return <Login cargaToken={this.cargaToken} />;
      //return <NavegacionPrincipal />;
    }
  }
```

Entonces no hacer falta pasar params en home

```js
...
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    //Home: { screen: <Home tokenLlave={this.props.screenProps} /> },
    Home: {
      screen: Home,
    },
    Navegacion: { screen: Navegacion },
    Configuracion: { screen: Configuracion },
    ConductorInfo: { screen: ConductorInfo },
    SeleccionPPU: { screen: SeleccionPPU },
    Siniestros: { screen: Siniestros }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home"
  }
);
...
```

Simplemente en Home ya pudes usar `this.props.screenProps.token`